# Having trouble deleting specific directories within a specific parent directory

Tags: bash, shell, find, rm

I’m using Amazon Linux, bash shell.  I’m trying to write a statement that will delete all child directories named “target” within a specific master directory.  I would like to write things such that even if the directories don’t exist, there is no error thrown.  I tried the below but I’m getting an error

```
[jboss@mydevbox ~]$ find ~/.jenkins/jobs/subco/workspace/myproject/ -name 'target' -print0 | xargs rm -rf
xargs: Warning: a NUL character occurred in the input.  It cannot be passed through in the argument list.  Did you mean to use the --null option?
```

What is a better way to write the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `-print0` you should use the `-0` flag to `xargs` so it will read the names correctly.

```
find ~/.jenkins/jobs/subco/workspace/myproject/ -name 'target' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

alternately, if you have GNU `find` you could use the `-delete` flag, though it won't work if the directories are not empty

```
find ~/.jenkins/jobs/subco/workspace/myproject/ -name 'target' -delete
```

Or, you could also use `-exec` with find like

```
find ~/.jenkins/jobs/subco/workspace/myproject/ -name 'target' -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

Modern `find` (via POSIX, so the not-GNU `find` on OpenBSD does support this) can do the necessary work without a call to `xargs` via the `-exec command {} +` form.

```
find ... -exec rm -rf '{}' \+
```